# Larger file not getting uploaded and reflected using uploadify

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, uploadify

I am using uploadify plugin to upload files and update them in mysql database.

Smaller files are getting uploaded easily i.e. less then 1 mb files are getting uploaded and updated in the database.
But bigger files that is more than 4 mb or so are not getting uploaded.

Here is my code:
`

```
$j('#file_upload').uploadify({
        auto : false,
        'swf'      : 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : 'newuploadify.php',
        // Put your options here
        'queueSizeLimit' : 1,

        'multi'    : false,
        'buttonText' : 'Add Photo',
        'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
        'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.JPG',
        'fileSizeLimit' : '10MB',
        'onClearQueue' : function(queueItemCount) {
               $j("#photocancelbtn").hide();
               $j("#photouploadstartbtn").hide();
        },
        'onSelect' : function(file) {
              $j("#photocancelbtn").show();
              $j("#photouploadstartbtn").show();
        },

        'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                $j("#photocancelbtn").hide();
               $j("#photouploadstartbtn").hide();

               changeBtnText();
    }


    }); /* closing uploadify line*/

}); /* closing funciton line*/
});
```

`

The uploadify script:

`

```
<?php
/*
Uploadify
Copyright (c) 2012 Reactive Apps, Ronnie Garcia
Released under the MIT License <http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php> 
*/
// Define a destination
require('newconnect.php');
$targetFolder = '/Mysite/uploadify/'; // Relative to the root

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
    $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

    // Validate the file type
    $fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'); // File extensions
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    $fp     = fopen($tempFile, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tempFile));
    fclose($fp);
    $query = $mysqli->prepare("Update help.posts set Photo=? where Pid=?");
           $query->bind_param("si", $data,$pid);
           $pid=3;
           $query->execute();



    } else {
        echo 'Invalid file type.';
    }
}
?>
```

`

Please let me know whats the error. I can upload smaller files but not larger files, although the upload limit i have set is 10 mb and also updated php.ini max-file-size to 10mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it got solved! The problem was in the file format. The script was not taking .JPG (in caps) but was taking .jpg